# How can I get the number of records affected by a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

For `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` SQL statements executed directly against the database, most database providers return the count of rows affected. For stored procedures, the number of records affected is always `-1`.

How do we get the number of records affected by a stored procedure?

Comment: Set No Count was my issue as well. To test, execute your stored procedure in management studio and see if you get counts, if you do, then make sure you have an output varible.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Register an out parameter for the stored procedure, and set the value based on `@@ROWCOUNT` if using SQL Server.  Use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` if you are using Oracle.

Mind that if you have multiple `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`, you'll need a variable to store the result from `@@ROWCOUNT` for each operation.

Answer (score 49):

`@@RowCount` will give you the number of records affected by a SQL Statement.

The `@@RowCount` works only if you issue it immediately afterwards. So if you are trapping errors, you have to do it on the same line. If you split it up, you will miss out on whichever one you put second.

```
SELECT @NumRowsChanged = @@ROWCOUNT, @ErrorCode = @@ERROR
```

If you have multiple statements, you will have to capture the number of rows affected for each one and add them up.

```
SELECT @NumRowsChanged = @NumRowsChanged  + @@ROWCOUNT, @ErrorCode = @@ERROR
```

Comment: SSMS often creates this line `EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[usp_TEST_Update] ` the SP has an update and it returns the value for `@RC` which is an int. I assume that inside the SP at the end this should be written `RETURN @@ROWCODE` and this will be passed to `@RC`. Is this the case? Would `@ErrorCode` be an out parameter as well? How would you handle Errors?

Answer (score 39):

Turns out for me that `SET NOCOUNT ON` was set in the stored procedure script (by default on SQL Server Management Studio) and `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` always returned -1.

I just set it off: `SET NOCOUNT OFF` without needing to use `@@ROWCOUNT`.

More details found here : [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method#Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#remarks)

> When SET NOCOUNT ON is set on the connection (before or as part of executing the command, or as part of a trigger initiated by the execution of the command) the rows affected by individual statements stop contributing to the count of rows affected that is returned by this method.
> If no statements are detected that contribute to the count, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Comment: This works for me. My stored proc is just a simple insert statements, and it seems to be working. thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Good job on the reference.

Comment: The blogs.msdn.com link is dead.

Comment: Thanks @Deantwo, I updated it (with a better one coming from msdn).

Answer (score 8):

For Microsoft SQL Server you can return the `@@ROWCOUNT` variable to return the number of rows affected by the last statement in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 5):

[@@ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

WARNING: `@@ROWCOUNT` may return **bogus** data if the table being altered has **triggers** attached to it!

The `@@ROWCOUNT` will return the number of records affected by the TRIGGER, not the actual statement!

Comment: Turns out this is not true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005225/sql-server-does-trigger-affects-rowcount