# SQL Server - does trigger affects @@Rowcount?

Tags: sql, triggers, rowcount

I have a query which do UPSERT or update if exists and insert if not:

```
update MyTable 
set [Name]=@NewValue 
where ID=@ID

If @@RowCount = 0 
insert into MyTable([Name])
values(@Name)
```

Now, I wonder if the `@@RowCount` will be affected by a query executed in a trigger? Let us say in my trigger I have:

```
insert into MyLogs(Description) 
values("Some description...")
```

If the update is successful in my first query, the trigger will run the insert to MyLogs which will have affected rows.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`@@ROWCOUNT` is tied to the scope of your current execution and is therefore unaffected by a trigger, which would run in a different scope.