# Get only result of update query

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I execute an update on my SQL Server database, I get a result of the rows affected by the  update **AND** the affected rows of some triggers.

So for example, an update executed directly on database:

```
UPDATE: (32 row(s) affected)
Trigger1: (1 row(s) affected)
Trigger2: (2 row(s) affected)
...
```

Now when I execute `_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, params)` I always get the sum of all those results, in my example the result value is `35`.

I only need the result of the `UPDATE`, in my example `32`.

Is there any possibility to ignore the results of the triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Alireza's answer makes the most sense if it's possible to change the triggers but if it's not could you change your database call to execute the update statement and return `@@ROWCOUNT`?

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("update xx ...; select @@ROWCOUNT");
```

I can't find any documentation on MSDN but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005225/sql-server-does-trigger-affects-rowcount) confirms that @@ROWCOUNT is unaffected by triggers.

Comment: This could be a better solution regarding this special case

Comment: yes, in my case for sure. Otherwise the cleaner solution is yours @Alireza

Comment: And we are here to solve `your` problem, of course. No anyone else's :)

Answer (score 3):

Put `SET NOCOUNT ON` on the first line of your triggers.

Comment: it's not possible for me to change the triggers, otherwise it would be a nice solution.

Comment: Is this because of a permission? Or there are other reasons?

Comment: Yes, it's a big database, used by several programs. So it's not that easy ;-)

Comment: Ok. I see. So it's hard but not totally impossible. I'm thinking of some another way.

Comment: with much begging it's MAYBE possible. But nevertheless i would prefer other solutions.

Comment: The problem is `SET NOCOUNT`'s scope is the current batch. Even putting a SET on a previous trigger will not apply it to the next. I give up!