# Getting No of records inserted in Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get the no of records affected from the stored procedure. Based on this value I want to update the user whether the action got completed.

But my OUTPUT `@RecordsAffected` parameter is always 0

**How to get the no of records inserted in the transaction?**

Followed [How can I get the number of records affected by a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201358/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-records-affected-by-a-stored-procedure) and http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/

This is my procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveRoleFeatures]          
(        
@RoleId INT,        
@SelectedFeatures AS IdInt READONLY,
@RecordsAffected INT OUTPUT      
)       
AS      

BEGIN  

set nocount on;

DECLARE     @ErrorCode  int  
SELECT @ErrorCode = @@ERROR
declare @trancount int;
set @trancount = @@trancount;

BEGIN TRY     

 BEGIN TRAN

     DELETE FROM RoleXFeature WHERE RoleIid= @RoleId  

     INSERT RoleXFeature      
      (      
       RoleIid,      
       FeatureId,      
       IsDeleted  
      )      
      SELECT      

       @RoleId,      
       Id,
       0    

      FROM  @SelectedFeatures 

COMMIT TRAN

              SET @RecordsAffected = @@ROWCOUNT

  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
    select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(),
             @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
    if @xstate = -1
        rollback;
    if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
        rollback
    if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
        rollback transaction SaveRoleFeatures;

    raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    return;

  END CATCH


  END
```

Comment: Try moving `SET @RecordsAffected = @@ROWCOUNT` before the commit

Comment: @Blorgbeard, Yes It is working. Thanks. But why it is not working after `COMMIT`? any idea?

Comment: @Billa Apparently because `@@rowcount` is supposed to return number of rows affected by the last statement, and `commit` is a statement that is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) to set `@@rowcount` to 0.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check `@@ROWCOUNT` before you commit.

As [@GSerg noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042007/getting-no-of-records-inserted-in-transaction#comment26394942_18042007), this is because @@rowcount is supposed to return number of rows affected by the last statement, and commit is a statement that is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) to set @@rowcount to 0.