# How to tell if a record is already exists in the database before executing stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure to insert data into a table in the database, but it should be unique so I check first for the incoming parameter:

```
create procedure SP_Insert
    @name varchar(50)
AS
    if not exists (select Name from Employees where Name = @name)
    begin 
        insert into Employess (Name) 
        values (@name)
    end
```

My question is, how to tell in my code if the passing parameter hasn't been accepted as a unique value after the execution of the stored procedure?

In my form I have a button (Insert) and a textbox (name), when the user click insert the text value is passed to the stored procedure, and I want to spring a message box warning the user of duplicated entry

Comment: so what if you had 20 people with the name `Mohamed` sounds like you need to have a different column(s) to check if a record exist also do some basic reading on `SQL` this will help you to better solution your issue.

Comment: that is what comes to my mind when I wrote the example above, my real table is Countries table.

Comment: then you should be showing your code / example based on the actual table.. come on now..

Comment: You should also avoid the sp_ prefix, or even better just skip the prefix entirely. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 1):

Use @@ROWCOUNT to determine that a row was affected and return the value as a parameter.  See this answer: [How can I get the number of records affected by a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201358/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-records-affected-by-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: Best approach here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
insert into Employess (Name) 
select @name
where not exists (select * from Employees where Name = @name)

select @@rowcount
```

Now the `@@rowcount` (returned to the caller) is either zero or one depending on whether there was an insert.

```
var recordsUpdated = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Actually you could skip `select @@rowocount` and not explicitly return anything.

```
var recordsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

That returns the number of affected records. I prefer to be more explicit. Someone could come behind and alter the procedure so that it does something else that changes `@@rowcount`. (Why? But they could.) And they might not know that something downstream is depending on that affected record count. But if it's explicit, whether a selected value or an output parameter, then someone can tell that something else depends on that value.

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure SP_Insert
@name varchar(50), @result bit output
AS
if not exists (select Name from Employees where Name=@name)
begin 
insert into Employess (Name) Values (@name)
set @result = 1
End
else set @result = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure can **return** a value. 
You can change your SP into something like this:

```
create procedure SP_Insert
@name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    if not exists (select Name from Employees where Name=@name)
    begin 
       insert into Employees (Name) Values (@name)
       Return 0
    end
    else begin
       Return 1
    end
END
```

Here is the link to MSDN article with more details and examples:
[[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx)

Comment: This won't work. The return statement returns an integer which is intended to indicate a status of the execution. If you want to get a value returned you should use an OUTPUT parameter.

Comment: Yes, a stored procedure can return a value - but **only** an `INT` value - not a string!!

Comment: @SeanLange I think this answer is correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210027/calling-stored-procedure-with-return-value
Please remove down-vote.

Comment: @Diego originally this was returning a string literal. I still would downvote this because it is using the return statement to pass data back. Data being returned should be using an OUTPUT parameter. It is even indicated as such in the article that is now linked to in the answer. But since it will at least perform the requirements I suppose I wouldn't downvote it.

Comment: @Diego I am guessing that you upvoted this to "offset" the downvote. That is not how this is supposed to work. If this was using output parameters it would be upvote worthy in my opinion.